# Jexcel removes all cells and leaves a number 1 on an if statement

Tags: javascript, jexcelapi

When trying to run an if statement with Javascript on a Jexcel to look at Cell 1,1 it seems to remove all the cells and leaves just one cell with a number 1 in it. I am new to Javascript so it is quite possible I am just not understanding it well enough, so dont be surprised if I have got the code completely wrong as my background is VBA. However if someone could just guide me on how to get it to look in one cell I am sure I can write the rest.

I have been trying to get the on-line guides on Jexcel to try understand it but I am not getting what I am missing. I have tried to follow the guide on the following https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jexcel/docs/JExcel-PGuide.html

but I am not getting exactly what I want it to do, which is look at the cell and follow a process depending if it is empty or not. It doesn't debug so I am not sure what else to try.

```
<script>
        function findIt() {
         var r = confirm("This will find all data, do you wish to 
proceed?");
      if (r == true) {
        $('#FRSTable').jexcel(data,{
        table: function (instance, cell, col, row, val, id) {
            cell =  worksheet.getcell(1,1);
            if  (cell() == null)
                {
                    alert("Please Enter a Value");
                }

            }                 
            });


      } else {
        alert ( "You pressed Cancel!");
      }

    }
    </script>
```

So what I expect is for it to say Please enter a value, what happens is all the Cells get removed and a single box with a number 1 replaces it, this resets after reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you are looking for actually is here. But, actually, jExcel brings a native searchable option.

```
<html>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.js"></script>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />


<div id="spreadsheet"></div>

<script>
jexcel(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
    csv:'https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/demo.csv',
    csvHeaders:true,
    search:true,
    pagination:10,
    columns: [
        { type:'text', width:300 },
        { type:'text', width:200 },
        { type:'text', width:100 },
        { type:'text', width:100 },
        { type:'text', width:100 },
     ]
});
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

The example above can be found at:
https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/examples/datatables